# Simple Service and Client Tutorial Problem

Tags: ros, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am going through the tutorial with ROS, and its been fairly smooth so far.  However, I just got to the section on creating a simple service and client in c++, and regardless of what I do, I keep running into errors when making add_two_ints_client.cpp and add_two_ints_server.cpp.  They both call on a header file called AddTwoInts.h, however the tutorial never went over what that was.  To compensate for that, I went and grabbed the TwoInts.h header file from the roscpp_tutorials package.  At first I put it under beginners_tutorials like the example suggested, but I received a message stating beginner_tutorials was not declared in this scope.  I did, however, get the code to accept TwoInts.h by just throwing it in src with the rest of the code and just calling

```
#include "TwoInts.h"
```

With that out of the way, I now receive an additional error down the line when I go to use TwoInts.  I go to call

```
ros::ServiceClient client = n.serviceClient<TwoInts>("add_two_ints");
```

but the compiler says it doesn't know what TwoInts is.  I then tried beginner_tutorials::TwoInts, then TwoInts::TwoInts, and even roscpp::TwoInts, but each time, it could not make.

My code looks almost identical to the sample code (aside from it being in a different location).  I keep going back to past tutorials hoping to find something that mentions TwoInts.h, but if its there, I can't find it.

Has anyone run into this?  How am I supposed to solve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10270/simple-service-and-client-tutorial-problem/) by [Tubbs](https://answers.ros.org/users/697/tubbs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-06-15

Post score: -2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At the top of the tutorial, in section 1.1, it says to make sure to build on two completed tutorials:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage
http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv#Creating_a_srv

I suspect that using those will resolve your issue.

---

Originally posted by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4